# What might be the possible causes of the following error in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the following:

       ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
       raise return select update while with <an identifier>
       <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
       continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
       savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
    06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
    *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

I am using a cursor. Cant share the code due to Copyright reasons.

Comment: unless we look at your code how can we even try to help

Comment: This is a syntax error. Somewhere in your code you are missing a comma or a keyword or a space. Or perhaps you have misspelled something. The message will have a line number, so you know your typo will be **in or before** that line.

Comment: This is a syntax error. Someone needs to review the code to let you know what you missed.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot share code, at least write anonymized version that throws the same error. Sometimes, when you try to replicate the issue you will find out what is the cause. PLS-00103 is usually hard syntax error so you might want to check whether your code follows basic syntactic rules https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL. Also the " " is sort of strange, since oracle does not care about indentation in the code. You also might want to check if your code contains non-ASCII whitespces - for instance in notepad++ use view->show_symbols->all symbols and look for spaces not marked by dot or an arrow.

Comment: For future reference, if you're going to point somebody to a syntax guide please use [the official Oracle PL/SQL Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm). Wikipedia is useful for many things but it is not authorative.